# GET the id of the inserted record

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to get the `id` of the inserted record with  the use of `getGeneratedKeys`. I dont know how to call `setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));` here to get the id? How can I get it to work.

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
ResultSet routesTables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "routes",
                        null);
                int route_id;
                if (routesTables.next()) {

                    PreparedStatement prepRoutesInsert = con
                            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO routes(direction, route)"
                                    + "VALUES( ?, ?)");

                    prepRoutesInsert.setString(1, direction);
                    prepRoutesInsert.setInt(2, route);

                  prepRoutesInsert.executeUpdate();

                     try (ResultSet generatedKeys = prepRoutesInsert.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                         if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                             setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
                            }

                     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated key is created automatically in the DataBase so there is no need for you to set it.
You can obtain it from the [Result Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

```
int id = generatedKeys.getInt(FIELD_INDEX);
```

Comment: I have changed this line to `     PreparedStatement prepRoutesInsert = con
       .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO routes(direction, route)"
         + "VALUES( ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);` but I am getting the error `" Column 'route_id' not found`?!

Comment: How does table definition look like in DB?

Comment: It wroks now I have your line to `int route_id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);`